# Maven Missing artifact com.adobe.aem:aem-api:jar

Tags: maven, aem

Hello I'm trying to learn HQL.

So I have a maven project and try to add this dependence

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
            <artifactId>aem-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Maven Missing artifact com.adobe.aem:aem-api:jar
and is returning this error can someone help?

---

### UPDATE

It appear thar this dependicy is from adobe public repository
so i add this in my pom.xml and appears to be working

I change my pom.xml and add:

```
  <repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>adobe-public-releases</id>
     <name>Adobe Basel Public Repository</name>
     <url>https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
   </repositories>
```

can some user with more experience in maven validate this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point maven to a repository that has the artifact you are including, in this case: `com.adobe.aem:aem-api:6.0.0.1`

My personal preference for AEM projects is to include the adobe repository in your `pom.xml` like so:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>adobe</id>
        <name>Adobe Public Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>adobe</id>
        <name>Adobe Public Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Of course, you can proxy the repo or include those repo settings in a profile in your `settings.xml` as recommended in this [adobe article](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/SetUpTheAdobeMavenRepository.html)